# Wrong SQL table structure

Tags: sql, syntax-error, create-table

I need a new table for a better clicked links tracking system, I tried with this:

```
CREATE TABLE tracker (
    id int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    link varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    clicks int(10) NOT NULL

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

But I got this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(id))' at line 6

Any ideas about what the problem is? How do I have to put the structure to make it correct?

Comment: you do not have a comma after `clicks int(10) NOT NULL`

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a , after the `clicks int(10) NOT NULL` column !

```
CREATE TABLE tracker (
    id int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    link varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    clicks int(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The comma operator is missing after the clicks int(10) NOT NULL column.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
CREATE TABLE tracker(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
link VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
clicks INT NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( id )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing comma near `clicks int(10) NOT NULL`.No need to mention `int` length

```
CREATE TABLE tracker (
id int NOT NULL auto_increment,
link varchar(255) NOT NULL,
clicks int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/487352